# displaying the content of an array which is composed of two other arrays

Tags: php

i have an array like this :

```
$finalArray= array($array1, $array2);
```

later, how should i do to display the content of `$finalArray` in a loop without knowing the name of the columns of `$array1` and `$array2` ? thx in advance :)

**EDIT**
i.e : to display the content of a simple array we do something like that :

```
foreach($array1 as $value){
         echo $value['the_name_of_the_columns']."<br />";
       }
```

how about an array of arrays :), i'm supposed to having to know the name of columns, i need to it independently on the columns names .

Comment: What's a boucle? And could you clarify what you're asking in the question?

Comment: Question is broad.. do you want to show the data? print_r?

Comment: boucle : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boucl%C3%A9

Comment: boucle? "an uneven yarn of three plies one of which forms loops at intervals"?

Comment: that's not how you display a simple array... `foreach($array1 as $value){
         echo $value."<br />";
       }
` that's how

Comment: you right, but i forget to mention that i store the content of the array from the data base, so my array contains the value of the columns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use foreach....

```
echo "first: <br/>";
foreach ($finalarray[0] as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
echo "second: <br/>";
foreach ($finalarray[1] as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

EDIT :

documentation on foreach:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php